# how to resend activation link from parse db

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm a php developer. Recently, I started using `parse db` using php. Whenever I create an account using the following code:

```
$signup= $user->signup($username=$uname,$password=$pswd);
```

parse automatically sending activation link.

But my requirement is sometimes, unfortunately, will delete that link at that time. How to resend activation link. Is there any way to do this.
Does parse allows us to resend activation link.

Answer (score 1):

If by "parse db" you are referencing to [parse.com](http://parse.com) and by activation link you mean "email verification", then the answer would be :

You have just to update the User's email field with the same email value and save it again. The verification email will be sent again.